# Desktop Safari browser and HTTP Live streaming

Tags: javascript, html, safari, html5-video, http-live-streaming

I suppose the *Safari* browser is supporting the HLS. I quickly tried it but streaming was not started - Is anything wrong with mycode?

```
<html>
<head> 
  <title>HTTP Live Streaming</title>
</head>

<body>
<video controls src="http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8">
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

I am using the Windows version of the Safari browser 5.0.3.

Thanks
STeN

Comment: For what it's worth, your example code works for me in Safari 5.1 on a Mac (Mac OS X 10.6.8). I'm not sure, but i would guess that QuickTime has a role in HLS streaming in Safari, so what's installed and not for QuickTime on the client is probably a factor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTTP Live Streaming is supported on Safari on Mac through Quicktime X which is available on Snow Leopard and Lion.  Quicktime 7 is also used on Mac for media functions that are not yet available in Quicktime X.    On Windows, Quicktime 7 is available but not Quicktime X.   So Safari on Windows does not support HTTP Live Streaming.

Answer (score 0):

I was reading the apples documentation and I found that you can define alternate sources

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH2-SW1l

something like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

   <head>

      <title>Multi-Scheme Video Player</title>

   </head>

   <body>

      <video controls autoplay >

             <source src="http://HttpLiveStream.m3u8">

             <source src="rtsp://LegacyStream.3gp">

             <source src="http://ProgressiveDownload.m4v">

      </video>

  </body>

</html>
```

You could try it with just one source.

But I also found some information suggesting to use httlive:// instead of http://

Comment: Hi, I must use the HLS - this is preferred and the only used stream protocol the customer is using. I do not have the possibility to switch to RTSP or use the http progressive download. I have tried the different HLS streams available on the Internet on the Safari mobile browser on iPad and there it works, so I suppose this is the Savari 5.0.3 Windows (desktop) problem - seems it is not supported...

Comment: hello, it would make sense then. safari for windows is not really as reliable as the the one for mac. I wish I could help more :(